# Show the badges you can't earn apart

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request, tag-badges

This an extension to a previous question:

[Don't show Cleanup badge until you can earn it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259191/dont-show-cleanup-badge-until-you-can-earn-it)

For example: If I can't earn the *Cleanup badge*, show the badge separated from the others I can earn. And if I can't earn it, show the requirements to reach the possibility to earn the badge

Comment: You can earn cleanup. Did you read that discussion thoroughly?

Comment: It's an example, for the critic badge you must have at least 125 of reputation, if I haven't that level, show it apart

Comment: The answer on the dupe can go nicely on this question.

Answer (score 3):

> If i can't earn the cleanup badge,

You *can* earn the [cleanup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/4/cleanup) badge, because you *can* roll back your posts to revisions you please. Now this is sometimes misused, as the OPs don't cooperate with the community and get into *rollback wars*.

From your comment (which makes it clear why you want this):

> It's an example, for the critic badge you must have at least 125 of reputation, if I haven't that level, show it apart.

Now, we can't really *not* show them. Badges are there. The ones you *can't* still earn are there, to give you an incentive to be constructive and active, and reach the minimum requirements for those badges. If you don't ever know there's a badge for reviewing stuff, you either

- Will see no reason (read: no fun) in doing so, and thus won't review, or
- Will not crave towards earning enough rep to review than you would've done before. <sup>1</sup> The gamification/privileges is sometimes a big reason for some people.
- Continue doing what you're doing, but this is a different case.

I think we can agree that it isn't such a good idea.

That said, I don't think showing them apart is really a good idea either. I'm aware that you want this as an arrangement so you can choose your next badge easier. <sup>2</sup> But what if someone else doesn't see it that way?

People are weird, and they get weirder in the internet. Someone who sees *badges you can't earn yet* on top of a list of badges *could* get disheartened because *I can't haz those shiny badges!* I agree this is irrational, but making "the badges you can't earn" more obvious is likely to cause irrational (sympathetic) reactions.

Furthermore, how will you define these? [There are some unearnable badges on every SE site, even stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/should-the-precognitive-badge-be-listed-in-the-list-of-sofu-badges). Also, I can say the probability of my getting a *guru* badge on one site I'm active is so negligible I can't assume I won't earn it. Should I "blacklist" that badge as well?

### TL;DR

This isn't a very good idea, as the arguments for are weak, and there are some hardships implementing this. SE can't [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) every feature-request.

---

1: Now don't get me wrong, people answer for a big variety of reasons. Some feel charitable, and some just do for the fun of it. But these people are unlikely to cause any trouble.

2: This reason's viability is still some kinda questionable.